# floating form items left and right?

Tags: html, css, css-float

**Problem**

I have several form items that i would like floated left or right. However i can't seem to get them to do as they are told (possibly as I'm not telling them correctly).

So i have two sets of form items

1. info about car ---- should all be on the left
2. info about person - should all be on the right

**What is currently looks like**

[image]

*as you can see ifs a mess!*

**My attempted solution**

to inline float each item left or right

i.e

```
 <div style="float:left">
              <label>Engine<span class="small">Engine Size</span></label>
              <select id="engine" name="engine-size">
                <option value="1.0 Litre">1.0 Litre</option>
                <option value="1.6 Litre">1.6 Litre</option>
                <option value="1.2 Litre">1.2 Litre</option>
                <option value="2.5 Litre">2.5 Litre</option>
                <option value="3 Litre">3 Litre</option>
                <option value="4+ Litre">4+ Litre</option>
              </select>
              </div>
```

However this approach doesn't entiry work as the "Model" is still on right side as well as "transmission".

**Complete Code**

> CSS

```
/* ----------- My Form ----------- */
.form1{
    float:left;
margin:0 auto;
width:900px;
height:500px;
padding:14px;
}

/* ----------- stylized ----------- */
#stylized{
/*border:solid 2px #b7ddf2;*/

}
#stylized h1 {
font-size:14px;
font-weight:bold;
margin-bottom:8px;
}
#stylized p{
font-size:11px;
color:#666666;
margin-bottom:20px;
/*border-bottom:solid 1px #b7ddf2;*/
padding-bottom:10px;
}
#stylized label{
display:block;
font-weight:bold;
text-align:right;
width:140px;
float:left;
}
#stylized .small{
color:#666666;
display:block;
font-size:11px;
font-weight:normal;
text-align:right;
width:140px;
}
#stylized input, select, checkbox, radio{
float:left;
font-size:12px;
padding:4px 2px;
border:solid 1px #aacfe4;
width:200px;
margin:2px 0 20px 10px;
}
#stylized button{
clear:both;
margin-left:150px;
width:125px;
height:31px;
background:#666666 url(img/button.png) no-repeat;
text-align:center;
line-height:31px;
color:#FFFFFF;
font-size:11px;
font-weight:bold;
}
```

> HTML

```
<div id="stylized" class="form1">
                <form id="form1" method="POST" action="">
                  <div style="float:left">
                    <label>Make<span class="small">Choose the make.</span></label>
                    <select id="make" name="make" required autofocus style="float:left">
                      <option value="Default"></option>
                      <option value="Alfa Romeo">Alfa Romeo</option>
                      <option value="Aston Martin"> Aston Martin</option>
                      <option value="Audi"> Audi</option>
                      <option value="Bentley"> Bentley</option>
                      <option value="BMW">BMW</option>
                      <option value="Daihatsu">Daihatsu</option>
                      <option value="Dodge">Dodge</option>
                      <option value="Ferrari">Ferrari </option>
                      <option value="Fiat">Fiat</option>
                      <option value="Ford">Ford</option>
                      <option value="Honda">Honda</option>
                      <option value="Hyundai">Hyundai </option>
                      <option value="Isuzu">Isuzu</option>
                      <option value="Jaguar">Jaguar</option>
                      <option value="Jeep">Jeep</option>
                      <option value="Kia" >Kia</option>
                      <option value="Lamborghini">Lamborghini </option>
                      <option value="Land Rover">Land Rover</option>
                      <option value="Lexus">Lexus</option>
                      <option value="Lotus">Lotus </option>
                      <option value="Maserati">Maserati </option>
                      <option value="Mazda"> Mazda</option>
                      <option value="Mercedes-Benz">Mercedes-Benz </option>
                      <option value="MG">MG </option>
                      <option value="Mini">Mini </option>
                      <option value="Mitsubishi">Mitsubishi </option>
                      <option value="Nissan">Nissan </option>
                      <option value="Noble">Noble </option>
                      <option value="Peugeot">Peugeot </option>
                      <option value="Porsche">Porsche </option>
                      <option value="Renault">Renault</option>
                      <option value="Rolls Royce"> Rolls Royce</option>
                      <option value="Rover">Rover</option>
                      <option value="Saab">Saab </option>
                      <option value="Seat">Seat </option>
                      <option value="Skoda">Skoda </option>
                      <option value="Smart" >Smart</option>
                      <option value="Subaru">Subaru </option>
                      <option value="Suzuki">Suzuki</option>
                      <option value="Toyota"> Toyota</option>
                      <option value="TVR">TVR </option>
                      <option value="Vauxhall"> Vauxhall</option>
                      <option value="Volvo">Volvo </option>
                      <option value="Volkswagen">Volkswagen</option>
                      <option value="Other">Other</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                  <div style="float:right">
                    <label>Name<span class="required">*</span><span class="small">Add your name</span> </label>
                    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="John Doe" required/>
                  </div>
                  <div style="float:left">
                    <label>Model<span class="required">*</span><span class="small">Add the model</span></label>
                    <input type="text" id="model" name="model"  placeholder="Model of Car" style="float:left" required/>
                  </div>
                  <div style="float: left; ">
                    <label>Body Type<span class="small">Add body type</span></label>
                    <select id="body-type" name="body-type" style="float:left">
                      <option value="Hatchback">Hatchback</option>
                      <option value="Saloon">Saloon</option>
                      <option value="Estate">Estate</option>
                      <option value="Sports">Sports</option>
                      <option value="Convertable">Convertable</option>
                      <option value="Sports Utility Vehicle">Sports Utility Vehicle</option>
                      <option value="Other">Other</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                  <div style="float: right;">
                    <label>Email Address<span class="required">*</span><span class="small">Add Email Address</span></label>
                    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="johndoe@example.com" required />
                  </div>
                  <div style="float: left;">
                    <label>Transimission<span class="small">Choose Transmission</span></label>
                    <label>Automatic</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="transmission" value="Manual">
                    <label>Manual</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="transmission" value="Automatic">
                  </div>
                  <div style="float:right">
                    <label>Telephone<span class="small">Add your Tel Number</span></label>
                    <input type="tel" id="telephone"  name="telephone" placeholder="UK Telephone Number" input size="10" />
                  </div>
                  <div style="float:left">
                    <label>Color<span class="small">Choose you colour</span></label>
                    <input type="color" id="colour" name="colour" style="height:15px; width" required/>
                  </div>
                  <div style="float:right">
                    <label>Message<span class="required">*</span><span class="small">Additional Info</span></label>
                    <textarea id="message" stname="message" placeholder="Your message must be greater than 20 charcters" required data-minlength="20"></textarea>
                  </div>
                  <div style="float:left">
                    <label>Engine<span class="small">Engine Size</span></label>
                    <select id="engine" name="engine-size">
                      <option value="1.0 Litre">1.0 Litre</option>
                      <option value="1.6 Litre">1.6 Litre</option>
                      <option value="1.2 Litre">1.2 Litre</option>
                      <option value="2.5 Litre">2.5 Litre</option>
                      <option value="3 Litre">3 Litre</option>
                      <option value="4+ Litre">4+ Litre</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                  <div style="float:left">
                    <label>Doors<span class="small">Number of Doors</span></label>
                    <select id="doors" name="doors">
                      <option value="3">3</option>
                      <option value="4">4</option>
                      <option value="5+">5+</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                  <div style="float:left">
                    <label>Age<span class="small">Age</span></label>
                    <select id="age" name="age">
                      <option value="Less than 1 Year">Less than 1 Year</option>
                      <option value="2">2</option>
                      <option value="3">3</option>
                      <option value="5">5</option>
                      <option value="5+">5+</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                  <div style="float:left">
                    <label>Fuel<span class="small">Fuel Type</span> </label>
                    <select id="fuel" name="fuel">
                      <option value="Petrol">Petrol</option>
                      <option value="Diesel">Diesel</option>
                      <option value="Electric">Electric</option>
                      <option value="Hybrid">Hybrid</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                  <div style="float:left">
                    <label>Milage<span class="small">Milage</span> </label>
                    <select id="milage" name="milage">
                      <option value="10,000 or Less">10,000 or Less</option>
                      <option value="75,000">75,000</option>
                      <option value="100,000">100,000</option>
                      <option value="150,000 or More">150,000 or More</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                  <div style="float:left">
                    <label>Max-Budget<span class="required">*</span><span class="small">Select your maximum budget limit</span></label>
                    <input type="text" id="max-price" name="max-price"  placeholder="Maximum Price of Car" style="height:15px;" required/>
                  </div>
                  <div style="float:left">
                    <label>Min-Budget<span class="required">*</span><span class="small">Select your minimum budget limit</span></label>
                    <input type="text" id="min-price" name="min-price"  placeholder="Minimum Price of Car" style="height:15px;" required/>
                    <p id="req-field-desc">&nbsp;</p>
                  </div>
                  <div style="float:left"> <span class="required">*</span> indicates a required field </div>
                  <div style="float:right">
                    <input type="submit" value="Find My Car!" id="submit-button" />
                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>
```

Any pointers to what i need to do, or what i am missing would be great! Thanks

Comment: I wouldn't call that form "swanky"… at least not in its current state.

Comment: nope but hopefully it will be! lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, don't use inline styles.

Second, instead of having each field go left then right then left then right, try rearranging the form into 2 fieldsets, a left column fieldset and a right column fieldset (left being the car stuff, right being the personal stuff).  This way, you only need to float 2 things, one left and one right.  The fields inside those columns can just stack.

Note - I also added a `<div class="form-group>` around each 'part' of the form so they are block level.

E.g.

```
<form>

    <fieldset id="car-info">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Model<span class="required">*</span><span class="small">Add the model</span></label>
            <input type="text" id="model" name="model"  placeholder="Model of Car" style="float:left" required/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Transimission<span class="small">Choose Transmission</span></label>
            <label>Automatic</label>
            <input type="radio" name="transmission" value="Manual">
            <label>Manual</label>
            <input type="radio" name="transmission" value="Automatic">
        </div>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset id="personal-info">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Name<span class="required">*</span><span class="small">Add your name</span> </label>
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="John Doe" required/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Email Address<span class="required">*</span><span class="small">Add Email Address</span></label>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="johndoe@example.com" required />
        </div>
    </fieldset>

</form>
```

Example CSS

```
#car-info {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

#personal-info {
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
}

fieldset {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

label {
  display: block;
}

.form-group {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

**[Example](http://jsbin.com/nasinasi/1/edit)**

Comment: ok great thanks for the advice, I'll implement what you have said now.

Answer (score 1):

Related jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/7V4jm/

Try to separate the responsibilities of your files. Keep the content in your HTML and the styling in your CSS (try to avoid the `style` attribute in your HTML).

Take the car and people elements out of individual divs and place them inside a `car stuff` div and `people stuff` div:

1) Car stuff div

```
    <div class="column"> <!-- Car stuff -->  
            <label>Make<span class="small">Choose the make.</span></label>
            <select id="make" name="make" required autofocus style="float:left">
                <option value="Default"></option>
            </select>

            <label>
                Model<span class="required">*</span>
                <span class="small">Add the model</span>
            </label>
            <input type="text" id="model" name="model"  placeholder="Model of Car" style="float:left" required/>

            <label>Body Type<span class="small">Add body type</span></label>
            <select id="body-type" name="body-type" style="float:left">
                <option value="Hatchback">Hatchback</option>
            </select>

            <label>Transimission<span class="small">Choose Transmission</span></label>
            <label>Automatic</label>
            <input type="radio" name="transmission" value="Manual">
            <label>Manual</label>
            <input type="radio" name="transmission" value="Automatic">

            <label>Color<span class="small">Choose you colour</span></label>
            <input type="color" id="colour" name="colour" style="height:15px; width" required/>

            <label>Engine<span class="small">Engine Size</span></label>
            <select id="engine" name="engine-size">
                <option value="1.0 Litre">1.0 Litre</option>
            </select>

            <label>Doors<span class="small">Number of Doors</span></label>
            <select id="doors" name="doors">
                <option value="3">3</option>
            </select>

            <label>Fuel<span class="small">Fuel Type</span> </label>
            <select id="fuel" name="fuel">
                <option value="Petrol">Petrol</option>
            </select>

            <label>Milage<span class="small">Milage</span> </label>
            <select id="milage" name="milage">
                <option value="10,000 or Less">10,000 or Less</option>
            </select>       
    </div> <!-- End car stuff -->
```

2) People stuff div

```
    <div class="column"> <!-- Person stuff -->

            <label>
                Name<span class="required">*</span>
                <span class="small">Add your name</span> 
            </label>
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="John Doe" required/>

            <label>Email Address<span class="required">*</span><span class="small">Add Email Address</span></label>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="johndoe@example.com" required />

            <label>Telephone<span class="small">Add your Tel Number</span></label>
            <input type="tel" id="telephone"  name="telephone" placeholder="UK Telephone Number" input size="10" />

            <label>Message<span class="required">*</span><span class="small">Additional Info</span></label>
            <textarea id="message" stname="message" placeholder="Your message must be greater than 20 charcters" required data-minlength="20"></textarea>

            <label>Age<span class="small">Age</span></label>
            <select id="age" name="age">
                <option value="Less than 1 Year">Less than 1 Year</option>
            </select>

            <label>Max-Budget<span class="required">*</span><span class="small">Select your maximum budget limit</span></label>
            <input type="text" id="max-price" name="max-price"  placeholder="Maximum Price of Car" style="height:15px;" required/>

                <label>Min-Budget<span class="required">*</span><span class="small">Select your minimum budget limit</span></label>
                <input type="text" id="min-price" name="min-price"  placeholder="Minimum Price of Car" style="height:15px;" required/>
                    <p id="req-field-desc">&nbsp;</p><span class="required">*</span> indicates a required field 

     </div> <!-- End person stuff -->
```

Then add a `column` class to both divs with the following styling:

```
/* ----------- Columns ----------- */
.column {
    width: 45%; /* or whatever width you prefer */
    float: left;
}
```

Related jsfiddle link again: http://jsfiddle.net/7V4jm/